# How to get rid of border in datagrid cell content?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, borderless

I am using regular WPF datagrid.
I want to get rid of the anoying border around the item in cell. Which property should I use to remove it?

I am actually using celltemplate to set the same behavior in column.

[Annoying border] https://i.ibb.co/ryxTfYB/anoyingborder.png

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field" Width="130"  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="FieldType" IsEditable="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding FieldTypeComboList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Type, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            MaxDropDownHeight="300">
                            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Hi, please show some code. What have you tried already? [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: because I am using cell template I don't know how to set the same styling in column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting `BorderThickness="0"` on combobox and match the combobox height with the cells height

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```